# Flutter how to call Link together with method

Tags: flutter, hyperlink, onpress

`import 'package:url_launcher/link.dart';`

How to call `followLink` and `launchUrl()`

```
child: Link(
target: LinkTarget.blank,
uri: Uri.parse('https://www.google.com'),
builder: (context, followLink) =>
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: followLink,
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: constants.appBarColor),
  child: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 4.5,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        'Visit Link',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 4.05
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),)
```

I need to call this method `launchUrl()` after clicking onPress

```
Future launchUrl() async{
await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 900)).whenComplete(() => {
  showToastWidget('Link clicked', Colors.green),
  callPointsPerClick();
});}
```

I tried this code below the `launchUrl()` is working but the `followLink` is not

```
  onPressed: (){
followLink;
launchUrl();}
```

Comment: You're missing parentheses after `followLink`, so it's not a function call. VTC as typo.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Modify your snippet to add parentheses at the end of `followLink;` line before the semicolon `;` to actually call the method like the following:

```
onPressed: (){
  followLink();
  launchUrl();
}
```

---

### In Details

When you type a method name only without the parentheses that means you are only referencing it and when you add the parentheses to the name that means you are calling it.

When the code was like this:

```
onPressed: followLink,
```

It worked because you are telling the `ElevatedButton` to take the reference of the `followLink` method to call it later when the `onPressed` occur, so you are just pointing the `onPressed` to the `followLink` to call it later.

While when you changed the code to be the following:

```
onPressed: (){
  followLink;
  launchUrl();
}
```

It did not work because here you don't need to pass a reference for the method, you need to actually call it because the callback reference is the anonymous method it self and the body of the method is the actually instructions to be performed.

Accoring to that, the line `followLink;` actually means nothing and you should be seeing a warning in the editor to remove it and the line `launchUrl();` worked because you are actually using the parentheses to call the function.

So your ideal is correct but you have to slightly modify your snippet to be the following according to the mentioned reason:

```
onPressed: (){
  followLink();
  launchUrl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly close this thread, this is answered by @Moaz El-sawaf correctly. Thank you

```
onPressed: (){
  followLink();
  launchUrl();
}
```